# How to save image data using socket programming in c

Tags: c++, c, sockets, openssl

I have a client program in c that make use of openssl library. I want save the captacha image from https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp... When i send a request header i get this as response

```
Connected with RC4-SHA encryption
Received: "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: image/bmp
Expires: Sun, 23 Jun 2013 07:45:48 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=captcha.bmp
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCUTRADAT=IIHDAOKCHMAAJICNEOLNHMBI; secure; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 23 Jun 2013 07:46:47 GMT
Connection: close

"M"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, it is a bit complicated.
For simplicy, you need a http parser, check the [http specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).
You can also parse it your self by following steps:

1. parse status line or in other word the first line
2. parse http header until CRLF token immediately after a CRLF token indicating the end of the http header section, *Content-type* for the data type after the header, *transfer-encoding* for how to reassemble the data, *Content-encoding* for how to decompress data after the header
3. read and parse the datato the end of buffer based on the meta constructed from step 2.

Your post shows you need do read the image until there is no data in the socket.
What's more, the file name is post here

> Content-Disposition: inline; filename=captcha.bmp

Comment: i am new to socket programming... Can u please explain a bit how to use a parser... And what i need to change or do... Am i sending a wrong request header ??? Thanks :)

Comment: [http parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser), is this what you need?